# Correct override of __rmul__ in cython Extensions

Tags: python, cython

How I must override **rmul** in cython?

For example, this works perfectly in python

```
class PyFoo:
  def __init__(self):
      self.a = 4
  def __mul__(self,b):  return b*self.a
  def __rmul__(self,b): return self*b

Pynew = PyFoo()

print "   Python   "
print Pynew*3 # I got 12
print 3*Pynew # I got 12
```

But, if I implement the same in Cython doesn't work,

cclass.pyx

```
cimport cython

cdef class Foo:
  cdef public int a
  def __init__(self):
      self.a = 4
  def __mul__(self,b):  return b*self.a
  def __rmul__(self,b): return self*b
```

test.py

```
import cclass as c
Cnew = c.Foo()
print "   Cython   "
print Cnew*3 # This works, I got 12
print 3*Cnew # This doesn't
```

I got this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    print 3*Cnew
  File "cclass.pyx", line 8, in cclass.Foo.__mul__ (cclass.c:763)
    def __mul__(self,b):  return b*self.a
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I don't understand what is the problem with use the same implementation of **rmul** in Cython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of not reading the documentation. In the [Special Methods of Extension Types](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/special_methods.html) user guide you will find the following:

> Arithmetic operator methods, such as __add__(), behave differently
>   from their Python counterparts. There are no separate “reversed”
>   versions of these methods (__radd__(), etc.) Instead, if the first
>   operand cannot perform the operation, the same method of the second
>   operand is called, with the operands in the same order.
>
> This means that you can’t rely on the first parameter of these methods
>   being “self” or being the right type, and you should test the types of
>   both operands before deciding what to do. If you can’t handle the
>   combination of types you’ve been given, you should return
>   NotImplemented.

So you should really be doing some type checking, atleast in the following way:

```
cdef class Foo:
    cdef public int a

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 4

    def __mul__(first, other):
        if isinstance(first, Foo):
            return first.a * other
        elif isinstance(first, int):
            return first * other.a
        else:
            return NotImplemented
```

This solution is overly optimistic concerning the use of the `Foo` class, you may need to check the type of `other` aswell, and/or check for a more generic *number* type.

Comment: Thanks! and yes, I'm guilty. I did't look in the documentation, I searched in google a lot (usually I got better answers there when the problem is that something that must be works doesn't).

My apologies, and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The Cython 3 alpha version should now support `__rmul__` that behaves in the same way as Python. So upgrading to that will make your code to work as written (it wasn't an option when the question was written though)